# What comes next? For 8 year olds

Tags: sequences-and-series, puzzle

This question is from the homework of my niece. She is 8 years old. And I could not help her with this question.

There are 5 x 3 cells. And there is a number in each cell. Problem asks what should be the "?" It should be one of 62, 76, ,79, 81. But I could not find a rule.

```
5, 4, 11
3, 7, 46
8, 6, 28
4, 5, 21
2, 9, ?
```

Any ideas? I remind you again. This is a homework for an 8 years old kid. So the rule should be simple but I am in vain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Square the second number and subtract the first.

Comment: Seems right. I was not expecting a rule which uses square operation.

Comment: Think of it as multiplying the second number by itself. Squaring is just multiplication.